What virtual keyboard to use with touch screen?
I'm quite struggling on integrating a virtual keyboard on my python app.
These are the virtual keyboard I tried and my problems on each one.
I'm on Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm on a Raspberry Pi 5.
matchbox-keyboard
On this keyboard I got an extremely strange bug that happened when my app is in Fullscreen mode (Need to clic 1 time with a mouse on the virtual keyboard).
This bug also occur when a popup is showed, the user cannot click ok with the touch screen but can close the popup.
This is a simple script where I replicated the bug:
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess
import psutil

def open_virtual_keyboard(event):
    global keyboard_process
    if keyboard_process is None or keyboard_process.poll() is not None:
        keyboard_process = subprocess.Popen(['matchbox-keyboard'])

        root.after(100, lambda: event.widget.focus_force())
        print("Opening a virtual keyboard")


def close_virtual_keyboard(event=None):
    global keyboard_process
    root.after(100, check_focus)
    print("Closing the virtual keyboard")

def check_focus():
    global keyboard_process
    focused_widget = root.focus_get()
    if not isinstance(focused_widget, tk.Entry):
        if keyboard_process is not None:
            keyboard_process.terminate()
            keyboard_process = None

def on_closing():
    close_virtual_keyboard()
    for proc in psutil.process_iter(['name']):
        if proc.info['name'] == 'matchbox-keyboard':
            proc.terminate()
    root.destroy()

def handle_click(event):
    if not isinstance(event.widget, tk.Entry):
        close_virtual_keyboard()

keyboard_process = None

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Virtual keyboard App")
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

# BUG
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
root.geometry(f"{screen_width}x{screen_height}")
root.update()
# BUG



entry1 = tk.Entry(root)
entry1.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

entry2 = tk.Entry(root)
entry2.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

for entry in (entry1, entry2):
    entry.bind("<FocusIn>", open_virtual_keyboard)
    entry.bind("<FocusOut>", close_virtual_keyboard)

root.bind("<Button-1>", handle_click)

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)

root.mainloop()

wvkbd-mobintl
When my app is in Fullscreen mode I don't manage to bring the virtual keyboard to the front. Even thought I tried a lot of things with xdotool and other tools.
onboard
I don't manage to show the keyboard and hide it, I tried with dbus-send.
Edit
I stayed with matchbox-keyboard.
I ran a script found online:
xinput list
read -p "Enter the device ID of your touchscreen: " device_id

xinput set-prop $device_id "libinput Tapping Enabled" 1

sudo mkdir -p /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
sudo tee /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf > /dev/null <<EOF
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "libinput touchscreen catchall"
    MatchIsTouchscreen "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "libinput"
    Option "Tapping" "on"
EndSection
EOF

xinput_calibrator --device $device_id

And found the cause of the bug. When I used a mouse and my touch screen, the bug happened.
So I just disconnected my mouse and use my raspberry only with the touch screen.

maybe don't use external program but use grid() with tkinter.Button to create own keyboard directly in tkinter.

see CTkPopupKeyboard created for customtkinter

you can also ask on similar portal for Raspberry Pi or on official forum Raspberry Pi. I found this post on forum: tkinter numpad on entry click - Raspberry Pi Forums. It use grid() with tkinter.Button to create numpad.
